# Is there a way to interact with my Windows clipboard when SSH'd from an Exceed xterm?

Tags: ssh, rhel, windows, clipboard

I'm not sure which parts of my setup are relevant to my question, so I'll try to be as explanatory as possible...

I'm using a Windows 10 laptop, and using Exceed on Demand to open an Xterm.  I then use that Xterm to SSH to multiple different systems (RHEL8) to which I don't have privileges to install new packages.

There are frequently blocks of text I'd like to copy out of the Xterm to paste in a Windows app, but in order to do that I need to do one of two things:

1. Open up Cygwin and use scp/rsync through a bunch of proxies so that I can get the source text file in Windows
2. I can change the font size of my xterm to be very small so that I can copy a bunch of text by highlighting.  But this has its limitations (can't copy more than one xterm screen at a time), and it's annoying to change the font size.

Is there any natively accessible with standard RHEL8 way to do what I'm trying to do?  I'd love it if something like this was possible:

```
echo "Copy me!!!" > /dev/clipboard
```

I guess I don't really understand how data is transferred to/from Windows to whatever SSH session I'm in... it doesn't seem like there could be a way for Windows to get the data in the way I want to provide it, but I figured I'd ask anyway.

Answer (score -1):

SSH mostly just moves characters back and forth (it's modeled on TELNET which was modeled on serial cables).  It's roughly equivalent to what the `cat` command can do.  Anything fancier is done with sequences of control characters sent by the remote host (typically [ANSI escapes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code)).

Do you have to use xterm via X?  (I believe "Exceed On Demand" is an X server implementation, right?)  I'd suggest running an SSH client on Windows natively, with or as-part-of, a terminal emulator also running on Windows.  Many terminal emulators give you the ability to capture the text stream to a file.

[PuTTY](https://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/%7Esgtatham/putty/) is an Open Source program which is very popular for this; it has a log-to-file feature.

A commercial product I've used in the past was [SecureCRT](https://www.vandyke.com/products/securecrt/).  You'd have to pay for it, but it offers more GUI and hand-holding and such than PuTTY.  I found it to be of excellent quality at the time, although that was some years ago now.